# Is there any way to build native (Android) application using Sencha Cmd on Linux?

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I couldn't build native **Android** application through Sencha Cmd despite I tried different versions including latest one(v4.0.2.67) with Phonegap/Cordova on **Linux**. Is there any way to build native applications using Sencha Cmd on **Linux**?

Software stack that I use:

- Sencha Touch **2.3.1**
- Ubuntu **12.04**
- Sencha Cmd **v4.0.2.67**
- Cordova **3.3.0**
- Phonegap **2.9.1**

Getting this error:

```
stbuild is not yet supported on linux
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because now you have to use cordova to build the apps.
Follow the instructions [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/cordova) for a details guide.

Basically, before building, install cordova

> `npm install -g cordova`

And then enable cordova support in your project:

> `sencha cordova init [AppID]`

Then, your good to go!